# OpenEarsEventObserverDelegate Methods are not call

Tags: iphone, objective-c, voice-recognition, openears

I am making an voice recognition application which recognize my voice in the absence of network for this I am using `OpenEars` sdk. I have taken a sample code of it and I have made a similar app of sample code but in my code my `openearsEventDelegate` methods are not call.
I have adopt the protocol `<openEarsEventObserverDelegate>`  and in my `viewDidLoad` method I have set `openEarseventObserver.delegate=self`.

Please guide me if I am missing something.
Thank you.

Comment: This link might get you started: [Delegate Methods not being called](http://www.politepix.com/forums/topic/delegate-methods-not-being-called)

Comment: Is there any warning or something ? Did you add the confirm to protocol syntax on .h ? Also check you are setting the delegate to self.

Comment: Just follow the tutorial at http://www.politepix.com/openears/tutorial in order to create your own app. It covers how to connect the OpenEarsEventsObserver delegate in copy/paste-able form.

Comment: Jeremy, that link was to a discussion that didn't apply to 1.x versions of OpenEars so I archived the discussion and it won't be available there anymore (it would unfortunately give the impression that there are multiple steps to follow when setting the OpenEarsEventsObserver delegate should be like setting any other delegate).

Comment: BTW, the protocol is OpenEarsEventsObserverDelegate so the issue might be the lowercase 'o' in your declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Without more code it's hard to say exactly what your problem is, but here are a few things I would try:

Ensure your OpenEarsEventObserver object is not nil when you set the delegate:

```
        OpenEarsEventsObserver* openEarsEventsObserver = [[OpenEarsEventsObserver alloc] init];
        [openEarsEventsObserver setDelegate:self];
```

Make sure your pocketsphinxController is not nil and that you have correctly started listening, for this I use lazy instantiation:

```
   - (PocketsphinxController *)pocketsphinxController {
      if (_pocketsphinxController == nil) {
          _pocketsphinxController = [[PocketsphinxController alloc] init];
          }
     return _pocketsphinxController;
    }
```

Then when you would like to start recognizing speech use:

```
      [self.pocketsphinxController startListeningWithLanguageModelAtPath:<#(NSString *)#> dictionaryAtPath:<#(NSString *)#> acousticModelAtPath:<#(NSString *)#> languageModelIsJSGF:<#(BOOL)#>];
     // Change "AcousticModelEnglish" to "AcousticModelSpanish" to perform Spanish recognition instead of English.
```

All of this info can be found at: [OpenEars Tutorials](http://www.politepix.com/openears/tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. When I tried to set the delegate before starting listening `self.openEarsEventsObserver` was `nil` so you can simply check if it's nil before starting listening and then set a new OpenEarsEventsObserver instance to your property. It was a quick fix for me.